# Remove tabs and spaces from text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file having text below:

```
Contact Name            |           Contact Number
```

Above like `Contact Name\t\t|\t\tContact Number` And i am using the following code to remove `\t\t|\t\t` :

```
 using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string s = String.Empty;
                while ((s = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
                {
                 string[] line = s.Split(new string[] {"\t\t|\t\t"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
                }
            }
```

I am using the breakpoint to check the values in the "line" variable below:

```
"Contact Name"
"Contact Number\r\n\r\n"
```

The above line of code remove `\t\t|\t\t` but add `\r\n\r\n`. How do I remove both `\t\t|\t\t` and `\r\n\r\n` at a time. Kindly suggest me. Waiting for reply. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Split your text by `|` char and then trim each line by removing tabs, spaces and new line characters from start and end of each line (you can also use `Trim()` without parameters in this case, because all characters you want to remove are considered white space characters):

```
string text = "Contact Name            |           Contact Number";
var lines = text.Split('|').Select(s => s.Trim('\t', '\n', '\r', ' '));
```

That will produce sequence of two lines:

```
"Contact Name"
"Contact Number"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s = s.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
```

This will remove all newline characters from end of your string.

Comment: I think you also need to add '\t' character for trimming

Comment: Efficiency aside, if you're to do first split by '|' only, you can then trim (not just at end) all strings you get by {'\r', '\n', '\t', ' '} and get same result. It might be more general solution, and cover a few more cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since you try to remove all characters (like \t, \n or \r) from your file, I would recommend you to read all the filecontent as a string and perform a simple [`.Replace(string oldChar, string newChar)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is slightly faster than using the `.Split('').Join('')` method.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName)) 
{
    String line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
}
string content = sb.ToString();

// Remove all tabs and new lines
string cleanedContent = content.Replace('\t', String.Empty)
                               .Replace('\r', String.Empty)
                               .Replace('\n', String.Empty)
                               .Replace('|', String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also split on "\r\n\r\n" and it will be removed.

```
string[] line = s.Split(new string[] {"\t\t|\t\t", "\r\n\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
```